# JavaScript replace function with regex

Tags: javascript

I am learning java script and am currently learning regex. I study on my own and practice. I have some random code from the C program in which there is a for loop, I want to use java script and regex to replace the for loop in the while loop. If I change the code in the while loop when I click the button, how do I do that?

ps. I know the questions are weird and beginner but I’m just just learning and want to learn

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  

    <div id="content">
      <code>
        #include
        int main() {
        int i,x;
        scanf("%d", &x);
        for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", i, pow(x,i));
        }
        return 0;
        }
        
    </code>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
          <button id="btnText">Klikni</button>
        </div>
    </div>

  <script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you link your `java.js` code? To run a JavaScript function when a JavaScript button is clicked, you can use `document.querySelector("#btnText").onclick = funcToRunWhenClick`.

Comment: You could start by using punctuation in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex works only for simple cases. If you have braces inside of the loop, will not work.
The logic:

- Search for `<SPACE_>for<SPACE_OPTIONAL>(` (the first space is group 1, and is to prevent catching false positives, like function with name `myFuncWithSufix_for(params)`);
- Then for everything until `;` (group 2, containing the assign variable);
- Then for everything until `;` (group 3, containing the condition);
- Then for everything until `)` (group 4, containing the increment);
- Then for everything between `{` and `}`  (group 5, containing the loop body);

The flag `g`, means global, and will apply this regex multiple times if you have multiple `for loops`;
After this, the replace is trivial :)

```js
function replaceForLoopIntoWhileLoop(){
  var code = document.getElementById('content').children[0].innerText;
  var newCode= code.replace(/(\s)for\s*\(([^;]+);([^;]+);([^)]+)\)\s*\{([^}]*)\}/g, '$1$2;\nwhile($3) {\n$5\n$4;\n}');
  document.getElementById('content').children[0].innerText = newCode;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  

    <div id="content">
      <code>
        #include
        int main() {
        int i,x;
        scanf("%d", &x);
        for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", i, pow(x,i));
        }
        return 0;
        }
        
    </code>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
          <button id="btnText" onclick="replaceForLoopIntoWhileLoop()">Klikni</button>
        </div>
    </div>

  <script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```